# jQuery fade in/out on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein

I have links in the following structure and I would like to know what the jQuery/css should be to hide the `<img />` tags and fade them in on mouseover.

The idea here is that the HTML <img> is hidden and fades in on mouseover to provide a smooth effect.

Meanwhile a CSS background shows in the beginning.

**HTML:**

> <div id="nav">
>
> <a href="blah" id="id1">
>
> <img src="hoverimg.png" alt="Link Text 1"
>   /> <span> Link Text 1
>   </span> </a>
>
> <img src="hoverimg2.png" alt="Link Text 2"
>   /> <span> Link Text 2
>   </span> </a>
>
> </div>

**CSS:**

```
#nav a span{
  display: none; /* Hide the text reader title */
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background url("bgimage.png"); /* I would ideally use the # selector for individual links.. */
}

#nav a img{
  /* what goes here so that jQuery works and so that we can backwards compatibility a:hover effect? */
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
???
```

On a side note, I've noticed that jQuery will run an animation multiple times if the target element is a child node that is nested a few levels deep. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @Moshe: You have one opening <a> but two closing </a>. Where the other one opens, just before the second <img>?

Comment: Type, I "handcoded" the &amp;gt;s etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `style="display: none;"` attr to the image html, and then use this:

```
       $("#nav").hover(
            function() {
                $("img", this).show();
            },
            function() {
                $("img", this).hide();
            });
```

(Modify effects for your needs if show/hide isn't what you need)

Comment: This will show. Use http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ to fade in and http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ to fade out.

Comment: I changed `$("#nav")` to `$("#nav a")` and it worked. Before i did this, all of the links would light up when I hovered over one of them.